# forgot password system in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, authentication, forgot-password

I want to make a login system, with the 'forgot password?' , this is the only example that i found..[forgotten-password](http://www.frodosghost.com/blog/2009/7/6/cakephp-forgotten-password.html)

but i have a problem with my auth permission... i put the link 'forgot password?' in my view login.ctp when I click on the link not allow me to redirect to /user/forgot.ctp and send me a message from my function beforeFilter() on file app_controller.php

this is my link in the login.ctp

```
 <?php echo $html->link('¿forgot password?', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' =>
 'forgot')); ?></p>
```

when I login it works, but when I'm not logged in doesnt work and send me the message error
which could be the problem?

Comment: You forgot to include the error message.

Comment: i think the error message came from...  function beforeFilter(){
  $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
  $this->Auth->authError = 'loggin first'; // error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't taken a look at the tutorial, but have you tried the `beforefilter` method in `users_controller`?

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('forgot');
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is one solution! or allow in app_controller.php function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('forgot');
}